# Upload in the background

Tags: android, ios, firebase, flutter, firebase-storage

I'm building a Flutter app and I'm using firebase Storage for the first time.

I'm quite confused by the official documentation, as I don't find a lot of information about background upload / downloads.

My goal is to continue uploading some files even if the app is in background.

It seems that the uploads/downloads [continues in background on Android](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/android/upload-files#handle_activity_lifecycle_changes):

> Uploads continue in the background even after activity lifecycle changes (such as presenting a dialog or rotating the screen).

And it's possible to get the latest tasks status with `StorageReference.getActiveUploadTasks()`.

On iOs however, I didn't find any explanation of how the app will behave once put into background.

Moreover, the flutter library doesn't seems to expose the `StorageReference.getActiveUploadTasks()` function.

How are you managing uploads/downloads when the user puts your app in background?
Is the behavior the same for iOs and Android?
How do you recover the tasks result in Flutter when the app is active again?